# LinkedIn authentication in Laravel app sometimes extremely slow

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, linkedin-api

I run an application that requires LinkedIn for authentication. The app is built using Laravel (5.4) in combination with the Socialite (3.0) package.

The problem is that fetching user data from LinkedIn after authentication takes in ~50% of the cases **over a minute, sometimes two minutes** while being quick the other 50% of the time. As can be seen in the Network tab snippet of Google Chrome below:

[image: Google Chrome Network data]

The implementation in Laravel is very basic with barely any difference in the sample code. The regular routes for social authentication are in place.

**Methods in the Login class:**

```php
/**
 * Log the user out of the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->flush();

    return redirect('/');
}

/**
 * @return LinkedInProvider
 */
protected function getDriver()
{
    return Socialite::driver('linkedin');
}

/**
 * Redirect to LinkedIn for authentication
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return $this->getDriver()->redirect();
}

/**
 * Callback from LinkedIn with user information
 *
 * @param Request $request
 */
public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request)
{
    $linkedInUser = $this->getDriver()->user();
    // ....
}
```

Does anybody have an idea what might causes this?

Comment: Have you tried other socialite drivers?

Comment: It could be possible, that the API of LinkedIn needs more time, so it would not be your fault.

Comment: @mimo Thanks for your reply! If the API needs more time as you say, how would I resolve the issue? It's not acceptable for a login to take that long. I cannot imagine that all the users of this API have this problem.

Comment: Like @NorrisOduro said you could check if the problem exists with other providers.

Comment: Other users also mention long response times from the api: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320108/linkedin-really-slow-response-time, the only solution for this is using another provider instead of likedin....